# Jquery variable losing value when element is deleted

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm grabbing the width of an image and storing it in a variable, then deleting the image. After I delete the image, the variable value reverts to 0. Is there a way to have this value stick or a different way to accomplish it?

Here's some code for the confused:

```
bgWidth = $('#widthContainer img').width();

     alert(bgWidth); // value equals the image's width
$('widthContainer').empty();
     alert(bgWidth); // value equals now equals 0
```

Comment: Can you post an example on jsFiddle?

Comment: `$('widthContainer').empty();` does not clear elements, but `$('#widthContainer').empty();` does.

Comment: Working fine for me - http://jsbin.com/ofifuk/7/. Which browser are you using? I looked in Safari.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you're missing `var` on `bgWidth = ...`, you're missing a `#` on `$('widthContainer')`, and you're missing `;` on both the second and fourth lines.

with those changes, this works as expected (in firefox)

http://jsfiddle.net/B6RGJ/

```
var bgWidth = $('#test #sub').attr('id');

alert(bgWidth); // value equals the image's width
$('#test').empty();
alert(bgWidth); // value equals now equals 0
```

I am using a div's ID instead of an image's width here, but it should not matter if you are storing it in a variable.

Comment: I should have reviewed everything (including the post) before I posted this question. The variable is being initiated way at the top since it's being accessed by other functions. I took it down to the bare minimum when making a fiddle and found out that my problem is being caused by something else in the overall script.

Sorry for the rushed question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you try it as a variable:

```
alert(bgWidth);
```

Comment: My fault. I typed this post out real quick and didn't realize that I made that a string. The question still stands.

Comment: There's no reason it should not work. A variable is a variable, and jQuery's empty will not delete it, only the targeted element will be emptied. Written properly (closing etc.) you should get the exact same value before and after the empty(), so long as you are not checking the image again and rewriting the variable after the image is removed.